# How can I get all non-empty columns and their contents?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I would like to know how I can filter out empty columns when using data from one part of the sheet in another without having to specify each column name since more columns can be added.

I found [this site](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/filter-out-blank-columns-in-google-sheets-using-query-formula/) and tried out the formula there but that seems like sometimes it will include the column (meaning it has a non-empty value) but then it does not include that value so the column looks blank but shouldn't be.

```
=ArrayFormula(Query(transpose(Query(TRANSPOSE({Query({'Test Data'!A1:Z1;Query({if('Test Data'!A2:Z<>"",1,0)},"Select "&JOIN(",","Sum(Col"&column('Test Data'!A1:Z1)&")"))},"Offset 1",1);'Test Data'!A2:Z}),"Select * Where Col2>0")),"Select * Offset 1",1))
```

I currently have this:

```
|            |   english   |     math     |   science   |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:-----------:|
| 8:30       | bob,jill    |              |             |
| 9:40       |             |              |             |
| 10:15      |             |              |   mike      |
```

I would like it to this (its okay for a row to be empty):

```
|            |   english   |   science   |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------:|
| 8:30       | bob,jill    |             |
| 9:40       |             |             |
| 10:15      |             |   mike      |
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way of doing this would be to re-pivot it again like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(A2:A<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&IF(B2:Z<>"", B2:Z, "♥")&"♦"&B1:Z1, )), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 <> '♥' group by Col1 pivot Col3"))
```

[image: 0]

---

if you want to keep all times you will need:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(A2:A<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&IF(B2:E<>"", B2:E, "♥")&"♦"&B1:E1, )), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 <> '♥' group by Col1 pivot Col3 limit 0"); 
 {A2:A, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(A2:A<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&IF(B2:E<>"", B2:E, "♥")&"♦"&B1:E1, )), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 <> '♥' group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COLUMNS(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(A2:A<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&IF(B2:E<>"", B2:E, "♥")&"♦"&B1:E1, )), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col2 <> '♥' group by Col1 pivot Col3 limit 0"))))), 0))}})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!